# Removing class from all images with JavaScript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am not very experienced with jQuery and i have to do the following task.
I want to remove class from all images in a web page without using jQuery.
I was able to find this fixed with JQuery but i ll need this fixed with JavaScript. I will appreciate it if someone will be able to guide me about this.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this function

```
/**
 * Removes all class attributes from all the images, if a class has been passed then it only removes that className
 * @param {string} [className=] optional parameter, only images with that className will be affected and will only lose that className
 * @returns {void}
 */
function removeImageClasses(className) {
    var validClass = typeof className === "string";
    var selector = validClass? "." + className : "";
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("img" + selector);
    for(var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        if(validClass) list[index].classList.remove(className);
        else list[index].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
```

This is a working demo

```js
(function() {

  var original = '<img class="blue"><img class="blue"><img class="green"><img class=""><img class/>';
  var images = document.getElementById("image-list");

  function removeImageClasses(className) {
    var validClass = typeof className == "string";
    var selector = validClass ? "." + className : "";
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("img" + selector);
    for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
      if (validClass) list[index].classList.remove(className);
      else list[index].removeAttribute("class");
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    images.innerHTML = original;
  }

  function onClick(id, callBack) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", callBack);
  }

  onClick("remove-blue", function() {removeImageClasses("blue")});
  onClick("remove-green", function() {removeImageClasses("green")});
  onClick("remove-yellow", function() {removeImageClasses("yellow")});
  onClick("remove-all", removeImageClasses);
  onClick("reset", reset);
})();
```

```css
#image-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

img {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

img.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

img.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="remove-blue">Remove Blue</button>
<button id="remove-green">Remove Green</button>
<button id="remove-yellow">Remove Yellow</button>
<button id="remove-all">Remove All</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div id="image-list">
  <img class="blue" />
  <img class="blue" />
  <img class="green" />
  <img class="" />
  <img class/>
</div>
```

Comment: @bilalawan I set up a working demo, if you want to test it

Answer (score 4):

A simple modern way:

`[].forEach.call(document.images, x=>x.removeAttribute("class"));`

another sleek newer way:

`for(let img of document.images) img.className="";`

an older safer way:

`for(var i in document.images) if(i-.1)document.images[i].className = "";`

another older way, better than the first (thanks @mplungjan):

`for(var d=document.images, i=d.length-1;i;i--) d[i].removeAttribute("class");`

Comment: @Jonasw - not clear if OP wants to remove the class property or a class from it

Comment: @dandavis looks like too many people edited this without being involved...

Comment: @mplungjan ive just seen *mplungjan edited* and thought you produced this editing mistake, sorry

Comment: Thank you so much all of you for your time and help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Which means he also tries to change the class of `document.images["length"]`, `["item"]` and `["namedItem"]` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vjw1a1dn/ -

Comment: @mplungjan: that's a good reason to use `for of`, but setting a prop on a number like length shouldn't break anything. feel free to edit in a `hasOwnProperty` if you think it needs it...

Comment: @dandavis it is normal and not old fashioned to use a `for (var i=0;i<....)` on a collection in my opinion - for of is ES6 and not globally supported

Comment: @mplungjan: you talked me into modifying it, thanks for the suggestion! now if only i could type without massive errors...

Comment: Lol @ `if(i-.1)`  - Wow, you really must insert something hacky in all your code ;)))

Comment: Too bad there is no "follow" here at SO

Answer (score 0):

This should do the task.

```
for(var i = 0, len = document.images.length; i < len; i++)
    document.images[i].className = "";
})
```